# Iterating through TableViewCells skips some

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have a tableview and in each cell there is a checkbox. I also have a "select all" button.

My problem is that when I click select all I want to update all the checkboxes to checked state. So from a list of 100 cells, all get checked but every 13th cell does not. To make it clearer, on my simulators screen are 12 cells visible that all get checked. When I start scrolling, the first cell that comes up is unchecked, and is then followed by 12 checked ones :S
When I scroll a little and click "select all" again, the skipped ones become also checked..

Anyone have a clue what am I missing?

This is the cell code:

```
class ListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var checkbox: UIButton!
var buttonState = false{
    didSet{
        if buttonState{
            checkbox.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "checked"), for: .normal)
        }else{
            checkbox.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "unchecked"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func checkboxAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if buttonState {
        buttonState = false                                  
    }else{
        buttonState = true
    }
}

func simulateCheck(){
    buttonState = true
 }
```

And here are some snipets from my controller:

```
 private var articleValues: [ArticleValue] = []{
    didSet{
        tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
func selectAll(){

    for i in 0..<articleValues.count{            
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)) as? ListTableViewCell
        cell?.simulateCheck()
        tableView.reloadData()          
    }   
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "articleValueItem", for: indexPath)

    // Cell Configuration
    let articleValue = articleValues[indexPath.row]
    if let articleValueCell = cell as? ListTableViewCell{
        articleValueCell.articleValue = articleValue
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create a property in your `articleValues` array to check that item and when you reload your data you set if checked on your `cellForRowAt`. Interacting directly to cells is not recommended, instead, use your data source.

Comment: I think in your selectAll() function, I would call reloadData() at very last of this function. Also, why don't you return `articleValueCell ` in your `cellForRowAt` function?

Comment: GIJOW Thinking out loud, the articleValues are connected to a database, and I don't think it would be a good idea to save the checkboxes state to the database. maybe though a tuple or a dictionary would do the trick?

antonio081014 Your first point is totally right on performance issues I suppose but I don't think this is the problem. Your second point... I have no clue why! Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UITableView` is backed by a data source. This means that you shouldn't change cells directly like you do here:

```
cell?.simulateCheck()
tableView.reloadData()
```

Instead you should keep a list of all the checked positions, maybe another array that has bools for each corresponding `articleValue` (this is not the best design).

var checkedValues = Bool

In your
`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` method you would then set the state of the cell:

```
articleValueCell.buttonState = checkedValues[indexPath.row]
```

In your `selectAll` method fill this array with `true` values  and then call `tableView.reloadData()`

```
private var checkedValues = [Bool]()
private var articleValues: [ArticleValue] = []{
    didSet{
        checkedValues = Array(repeating: false, count: articleValues.count)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func selectAll(){
    checkedValues = Array(repeating: true, count: articleValues.count)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "articleValueItem", for: indexPath)

    // Cell Configuration
    let articleValue = articleValues[indexPath.row]
    if let articleValueCell = cell as? ListTableViewCell{
        articleValueCell.articleValue = articleValue
        articleValueCell.buttonState = checkedValues[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}
```

Another mistake is that you should never iterate on all the cells in the table because they are reused, no point in going through your data source and getting a cell for each. It only makes sense to iterate through `tableView.visibleCells`. But like in your case, most of the time you don't need that either, you should just update your data source accordingly and reload the table or just the modified cell.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Still you mention that this is not the best design. Would you have another suggestion, or can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Maybe store the flags in a `Dictionary` instead of `Array`, and as a key use some kind of ID you have in the `articleValue`, or the entire `articleValue` object (but you have to make it `Hashable` for this)

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended that you refer to cells directly within a table view. The reason is that UITableViews have an efficient method of only loading the cells as they are needed (and deallocating them when they are no longer needed, e.g. the cell scrolls off screen). Because of this the cell you are try to refer to may not be loaded.

Instead you should interact with it via the `cellForRowAt` method. If you want to "select all" cells, you should create a property that stores the value of `checked` or `not checked` via a `Bool` and then set all of the `ArticleValue` elements to `true` for that property and reload the data inside `selectAll()`.

It could work something like this:

```
func selectAll() {
    articleValues.forEach {
        $0.checked = true
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}

// ...

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "articleValueItem", for: indexPath)

    // Cell Configuration
    let articleValue = articleValues[indexPath.row]
    if let articleValueCell = cell as? ListTableViewCell{
        articleValueCell.articleValue = articleValue

        if articleValue.checked {
            articleValueCell.simulateCheck()
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that my data is saved on a database and also sent to a server, therefore I want to avoid adding such functionality directly to my objects.